# Handshake timeout ERROR with ssl connection in RabbitMQ

Tags: ssl, openssl, rabbitmq

I am follow this [tutorial](http://www.gettingcirrius.com/2013/01/configuring-ssl-for-rabbitmq.html) of RabbitMQ with ssl connections.

I have configured the 5672 port for ssl connections and I am launching openssl tool

for testing the connection to the port in local(Is a offical docker container of RabbitMQ).

My rabbitmq.config is:

```
[{rabbit,   [ {loopback_users, []},
       {tcp_listeners, [5671]},
       {ssl_listeners, [5672]},
       {auth_mechanisms, ['EXTERNAL','PLAIN']},
       {handshake_timeout, 60000},
       {ssl_options, [
         {cacertfile, "/etc/rabbitmq/ssl/ca/cacert.pem" },
         {certfile, "/etc/rabbitmq/ssl/server/server.cert.pem" },
         {keyfile, "/etc/rabbitmq/ssl/server/server.key.pem" },
         {verify, verify_peer},
         {ssl_cert_login_from, common_name},
         {fail_if_no_peer_cert, true }]}]}].
```

Then I execute this command:

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:5672 -cert ../client/client.pem -key ../client/client.key.pem -CAfile ../ca/cacert.pem
```

And I get this error in the RabbitMQ logs:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 6-Apr-2016::14:16:06 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.696.0> (127.0.0.1:34977 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)

=ERROR REPORT==== 6-Apr-2016::14:16:06 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.696.0> (127.0.0.1:34977 -> 127.0.0.1:5672):
{handshake_timeout,handshake}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you see `{handshake_timeout, handshake}`, it usually means that something is preventing the AMQP handshake (as opposed to the TCP handshake) from completing. Following the network traffic with Wireshark might give you an idea of where in the handshake process you're failing.